# What does this kind of formatter mean?

Tags: c, printf

```
printf ("%#p [ buf  ] (%.2d) : %s \n", buf, strlen (buf), buf);
```

I never see `%#p (%.2d)` before,how does it work?

Comment: §7.19.6.1/6 says `#` converts the result to an _"alternative form"_.
However, as far as I see this item, applying `#` to `p` format specifier
results in an undefined behaviour.
So, I'm not sure `%#p` is really the original coder's intent(possibly typo?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/:

> Used with o, x or X specifiers the value is preceeded with 0, 0x or 0X respectively for values different than zero.
>
> Used with e, E and f, it forces the written output to contain a decimal point even if no digits would follow. By default, if no digits follow, no decimal point is written.
>
> Used with g or G the result is the same as with e or E but trailing zeros are not removed.

So it seems to do nothing in your case, since `p` is used to print a pointer address. I guess some compilers might interpret this differently, but I can't find any mention of it.

Answer (score 1):

`p` specifies to print an address (i.e. a pointer).  The `#` flag specifies "alternate form", which in this case, probably prepends `0x` to the output.

Answer (score 1):

It's a flag for the format identifier.
It will more than likely print out 0x before the pointed value (but I have not checked TBH)

A good explanation is found [here](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/FUNCTIONS/format.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is a valid use of the '#' flag:

- Used with o, x or X specifiers the
  value is preceeded with 0, 0x or 0X
  respectively for values different
  than zero.
- Used with e, E and f, it
  forces the written output to contain
  a decimal point even if no digits
  would follow. By default, if no
  digits follow, no decimal point is
  written.
- Used with g or G the result
  is the same as with e or E but
  trailing zeros are not removed.

It will most likely print an alternately formatted form for the pointer, appending 0x to the address.

Answer (score 0):

In your case (`p` conversion) the result is undefined according to the man page. Anyway, `%p` and `%#p` prints the same value on my machine (looks like 0x7FFFF000)